# How to write a condition that check if it's true for every value in an array in java?

Tags: java

Let's say I have an array

```
marks[]{12,14,17,13,15,16}
```

that has six exam marks for example. I pass the exam if I score 10 or higher. I automatically pass the module if all exams are a pass. How should I write my condition for the module to check if all values on the array are 10 or higher and therefore it should say that the module is passed?

Sorry if the question is badly explained, I'm new to coding and also new to this website.

Comment: How about a `for each` and a if? :)

Comment: Please see [ask] and https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: You need to try to solve it yourself then ask here if you have problems with code you've written.  Hint: loop over the array

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int[] numbers = new int[]{11, 13, 14, 52};

    boolean pass = allAbove(numbers, 10);

    System.out.println(pass);
}

static boolean allAbove(int[] numbers, int lowest) {

    for (int i : numbers) {
        if (i <= lowest) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the second part is doing? The part after static boolean

Comment: Sure. It takes in an integer array (containing all your numbers) and also the lowest number to match against. In your case, it's 10. As it should fail if any number is below the **lowest** parameter, it returns false at this first occurrence. It will go through the numbers one by one to check if it's lower than 10. If it doesn't find any match, it will go to the bottom and return true.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] marks = new int[]{12,14,17,13,15,16};
boolean passed = Arrays.stream(marks)
    .allMatch(elem -> elem >= 10);
```